# How to show Plancherel's Theorem for Fourier Transform implies $L^2$ Transform Convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Plancherel Theorem for the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-ist}dt$ on $\mathbb{R}$ states that
$$
           \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(s)|^2ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2dt,\;\;\;\; f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\cap L^1(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Without appealing to classical convergence results, can this result be used to show that
$$
     \lim_{u,v\rightarrow\infty}\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^{v}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds-f\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} = 0. \;\;\; ?
$$
Does anyone know of a nice way to show this?

**Background:** This is not a homework problem or something I found in a text. It would seem reasonable to expect this result because of the discrete version where Parseval's equality for the Fourier series implies $L^2$ convergence of the Fourier series; or, if $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal set in an inner product space, then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(f,e_n)|^2=\|f\|^2 \iff \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left\|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n -f \right\|=0.
$$

Comment: Prove it for a nice dense subspace of L^2, like smooth functions with compact support, and then approximate

Comment: I think you can use the differentials of gaussian functions.

Comment: @zhw do you have a way to do this without appealing to pointwise convergence on some subspace, using only Parseval's identity?

Comment: @mathreadler do you have a way to do this without appealing to pointwise convergence on some subspace, using only Parseval's identity?

Answer (score 1):

$f \in L^2$

$\hat{f}= \lim\limits_{u,v\mapsto \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^v fe^{-isx}dx$

multiply $f$ by a bump function $g_n$ with compact support in $[-u,v]$

such that $ \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}g_nf=f$ on $[-u,v]$

let $h_n=g_nf$$\quad$ $h_n \in L^1 \bigcap L^2$ and $\hat{h}_n \in L^2 $(Plancherel theorem)

Also $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\hat{h}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^v fe^{-isx}dx$

The good part is that the sequence {$h_n$} is uniformly integrable over $[-u,v]$: this follows from property of bump function.
These imply $\hat{f} \in L^2$

Fourier Inversion theorem:$$
     \lim_{u,v\rightarrow\infty}\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^{v}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-h_n\right\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} = 0. \;\;\; 
$$

Plancherel theorem:$$
     \lim_{u,v\rightarrow\infty}\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^{v}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-h_n\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} = 0. \;\;\; 
$$

for sufficiently large $n,u,v$:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-\int_{-u}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}_n(s)e^{isx}ds)^2dx \le \delta$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}({h}_n-f)^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-f)^2dx \le \epsilon$$

writing $(a-b)^2=(a-c+c-b)^2=(a-c)^2+(c-b)^2+2(a-c)(c-b)$ and by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f-\int_{-u}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds)^2 dx\le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}((\int_{-u}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds)^2+(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-f)^2)dx +(2\delta \epsilon)^{1/2}\le\delta+\epsilon+2(\delta \epsilon)^{1/2}$$

Comment: So you're appealing to classical convergence results for bump functions? What I was looking for was something similar to $L^2$ Fourier series, where $\sum_n |\hat{f}(n)|^2=\|f\|^2$ implies $\|\sum_{|n| \le N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}-f\|\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @TrialAndError are you referring to something similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson's_theorem

Comment: If that is the case you are looking at a formidable problem and you would have to go through the references in the link

Comment: Showing that the Fourier series converges in norm if Parseval's identity holds, is straightforward. In fact, it's a general Hilbert space property that norm convergence is implied by Parseval identity for the Fourier series. It should be possible to use the Parseval identity for the Fourier transform to prove L^2 norm convergence of the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform (which would not imply pointwise convergence.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes: letting $\chi_{-a,b}$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[-a,b]$, and knowing that $\widehat{f}$ exists as an $L^2$ function whether or not $f$ was also in $L^1$, certainly $\chi_{-a,b}\cdot \widehat{f}$ converges to $\widehat{f}$ in $L^2$. Since (by Plancherel) (isometrically-extended) inverse Fourier transform is a continuous map $L^2\to L^2$, the inverse Fourier transforms of $\chi_{-a,b}\cdot \widehat{f}$ converge in $L^2$ to the inverse Fourier transform of $\widehat{f}$, namely, $f$.